# Prove that a tangent line at a point X of a parabola bisects the angle between the point vector and axis vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, conic-sections

I'm trying to solve excercise $14.7.14$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$. I started with a parabola $y=\frac{cx^2}{2}$, where its focus is at point $(0, \frac{c}{2})$.

Then, expressed as a vector function of a real variable, the vector from the focus to the any point on the parabola is $X(x)=(x,\frac{c(x^2 - 1)}{2})$.

I would expect that the tangent line direction is $\tag{1} T(x) = (1, cx)$, and the axis line direction is $A=(0, 1)$.

I thought that I just need to prove that $\frac{XT}{\|X\|\|T\|} = \frac{TA}{\|T\|} = \frac{cx}{\sqrt{1 + c^2x^2}}$, because it would mean that the two angles are the same...but I don't get far with that.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

---

As pointed out in the answer, I had a typo in the focus location, as well as in the direction of the axis direction.

Actual focus is at $F=(0, \frac{1}{2c})$. The vector from focus to any point on the parabola is $X(x) = (x, \frac{c^2x^2 - 1}{2c})$. The tangent line at the parabola point is $T(x)=(1, cx)$. The axis line direction is $A = (0, 1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the right idea, but there are several errors in your set-up.

1. If the equation of your parabola is $y = \frac{1}{2} cx^2$, the focus is at $\left( 0, \frac{1}{2c} \right)$, not $(0,c)$.
2. For what it's worth, when I read "point vector" I first thought you meant the vector from the origin/vertex to $X$, when you meant the vector from the focus to $X$. The coordinates you found for the latter are fine after correction (1), but I  figured I'd point out that this is not standard terminology.
3. The axis line direction is any vector proportional to $\left( 0, 1 \right)$, not $(1, cx)$. Do you see why?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I corrected my question based on your comment, but I still don't see how to equate the two dot products. The LHS of the equation is quite hairy, and doesn't seem to cancel out to the nice RHS which is $\frac{cx}{\sqrt{1 + c^2x^2}}$.

Comment: Careful, you still have the focus at the wrong point: the $y$-coordinate is $\frac{1}{2c}$, not $\frac{c}{2}$. You got the correct dot product for the RHS, so once you get everything sorted the LHS should work out to the same thing (and it's not very messy).

Comment: Thank you! You are completely right, it really cancels out well!